# String destructor problem in RHEL5

Tags: c++, destructor

I have 2 questions in C++:

1. Is it right to declare the destructor as virtual in the derived class?
2. Sometimes the C++ application crashes in the string destructor on RHEL5. What do I need to take care of when compiling such that the application does not crash on RHEL5? Is there any website link to better understand this?

Comment: You need to paste some actual code that demonstrates this. (In relation to your first question, ideally the destructor is also virtual in the base class.)

Comment: Your problem almost certainly has nothing to do with the Linux you're using; it's a C++ and library issue.  There is far too little information here to answer the question of why your code crashes.  We'd need to see some sample code.  (One thing that comes to mind:  you might want to search on "heap corruption", since destructor crashes are a symptom of it.)

Comment: I very much doubt that this has got anything to do with RHEL5. The code crashes because you do something wrong *in code*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's no limit on the number of items you're allowed to post, so when you have multiple questions, please post them separately, especially when they're completely unrelated, as these two are. You're allowed to *edit* your questions, too, so I suggest you edit this to remove your first question and post it separately. But before you post it, check to see whether it's already answered here.

Answer (score 1):

1. From a practical point of view it doesn't matter, as its being virtual depends on whether the base class destructor is virtual or not. Still, it may be a reasonable choice to declare derived classes' destructors as virtual, both as a hint to fellow programmers and to allow for a possible future refactoring where this class might become the top of the hierarchy.
2. Without a code example it would be hard to say. One thing that you might try is to ensure that you do not have any global strings, in case you are facing an order of destruction problem among globals defined in different source files.

UPDATE: It just occurred to me that your two questions might be related. You aren't subclassing `std::string`, are you? If you do, that's a bad idea and it might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: To add to the UPDATE for the OP: You can often tell if a class is designed for subclassing by looking to see if it declared a virtual destructor. If it did not, then you aren't supposed to inherit from it. (Except for special cases like base class templates and some kinds of tag structs.)

Comment: Same logic can be used to justify why derived class's destructor should not use `virtual` keyword. If one applies Occam's razor, then only the base class's destructor should be declared virtual, adding `virtual` to the derived class's destructors just adds clutter.